# wondering if there was a way to generate an HTML table with separated categories

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering if there was a way to generate an HTML table where there is a category (via the `th` tag) and separated boards like below (ideally with a `td` tag)?

```
|--------------------------------------|
| Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3 |
|--------------------------------------|
|    Board1  |    Board1  |   Board1   |
|--------------------------------------|
|    Board2  |    Board2  |   Board2   |
|--------------------------------------|
|    Board3  |    Board3  |   Board3   |
|--------------------------------------|
|    Board4  |    Board4  |   Board4   |
|--------------------------------------|
|    Board5  |    Board5  |   Board5   |
|--------------------------------------|
|    Board6  |    Board6  |   Board6   |
|--------------------------------------|
```

I'm going to be automatically generating this table via PHP+MySQL. I have the category names printing out perfectly, but I'm having difficulties with the boards being put in the correct categories. (if someone can help me out with this one too, that'd be awesome.)

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm trying to make an automatically generated table of links to directories, separated by categories. The issue is that tables are generated with rows instead of columns. I was wondering if I can somehow do it that way instead.